# https rewrite not working for All in one security Brute force > rename login url

Tags: plugins, login, security, https

I am trying to set 2 security measures that seems not to work together:
https on the site, using a server redirect + Module rewrite in htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

And also a new login url with all in one security that seems to override the https with http, by not considering the https. It is actually displaying **http**://etc...).

How can I make All in one security take https into consideration before overriding the new login url ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just found out. I needed to define http**s**:domain.ext// in the general settings of the wordpress site. Now All in One Security use the https to rename the url.